# Is this bad practice: assigning a return variable

Tags: python, syntax

```
one = 1 
def add_one(one):
  two = one + 1 
  return two 

two = add_one(one)
print(two)
```

I'm assigning a returned variable with the same name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-variable-scope/) link for various `variable name scope` in Python.

The scope of a variable in python is that part of the code where it is visible. Actually, to refer to it, you don’t need to use any prefixes then.

There are 4 types of Variable Scope in Python:

1. Build-in
2. Global
3. Enclosing
4. Local

Your example uses `Local namespace` in your function `add_one`.

`two` variable will be local to your function `add_one` and will be destroyed once the function returns (as it's reference counter has been reduced to zero0. However, you have passed it's value to the caller by returning it. Your caller has another variable with the same name `two` (but in different scope). So, it will be different variable.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't bad practice.  This is because the variable `two` within `add_one()` falls under a different scope.

Thus, the variable `two` outside the method will not be affected by what happens in `add_one()`.